# FTP client in Java doesn´t work properly when sending commands

Tags: java, ftp

I am making a simple FTP client in Java using standard Java sockets. I have succeeded to connect to the server. Then I can send FTP commands like:

```
USER myUserName
PASS myPassword
```

and the output says that I am logged in to the server (I allways send the \r\n string with each command that I send to the server). When I send the command "ls" i get this response: `425 No data connection`

When I log in to the server from the standard FTP client from the MS Windows terminal I can use the "ls" command and get a list of all files and folders, but it doesn´t work in my Java application.

The FTP command "HELP" also gives different output in my client and in the standard FTP client in MS Windows.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use PORT or PASV to establish a data connection. The file list doesnt come over the control connection. You will have to read up on ftp. The commands of the ftp command in windows dont correspond 1:1 to the commands in the protocol that you have to use when implementing it yourself.

Comment: Oh, ok! So a session would look something like this:

`USER myUserName`
`PASS myPassword`
`PASV`
Then I get the ip and port as response on which I make a new connection to? So after entering the USER and PASS, is the thumb of rule to allways type the PASV or PORT command?

Comment: 1. question yes. 2. question: close, but not quite. the rule is before every LIST, RETR, STOR etc you need to use PORT or PASV for a new connection. So your login sequence might look like user, pass, pasv, list. Try sending FEAT to your ftp server and it should respond with all the commands it understands. maybe there is something interesting there for you.